# How to calculate concurrent users in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have created a test script with the below scenarios and having thread group count as 100 and ran it for 10 minutes.

1. Employee Creation took 1 minute during the test script design
2. Update Employee took 2 minutes during the test script design

**In the above mentioned scenario how many concurrent users will be on the system for 10 minutes?**

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if we have neither a script, nor the data. It's like saying "I drove from A to B for 10 minutes. Where am I now? And how do I get to London?"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a formula to predict or calculate concurrency as we don't know the number of samplers, response time, etc. so go for one of the following options:

1. Generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and look into Active Threads Over Time chart - it will show you the actual concurrency.

   [image: JMeter Active Threads Over Time]
2. If you don't want or can not generate the dashboard you can achieve the same using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) Listener which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) as a part of **3 Basic Graphs** bundle.

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager - basic graphs]